# Apache Camel Http and SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been trying to get a 2-way ssl/https proxy working with Camel.  I have been able to set up the Jetty Component using 2-way ssl and am now attempting to get it working with the Http4 component to complete the client side of the proxy.

When I route the jetty traffic to a log component, all is well and the 2 way ssl trust chain is fine.  When I throw in the Http4 component, it blows up with a peer not authenticated exception. I am using Camel 2.7.0

Here is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    JettyHttpComponent jetty = context.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);

    SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
    sslConnector.setPort(9443);
    sslConnector.setKeystore("/home/brian/jboss.keystore");
    sslConnector.setKeyPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setTruststore("/home/brian/jboss.truststore");
    sslConnector.setTrustPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setNeedClientAuth(true);

    Map<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector> connectors = new HashMap<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector>();
    connectors.put(9443, sslConnector);

    jetty.setSslSocketConnectors(connectors);

    final Endpoint jettyEndpoint = jetty.createEndpoint("jetty:https://localhost:9443/service");

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/brian/User2.p12")), "Password1234!".toCharArray());
    X509KeyManager keyManager = new CTSKeyManager(keystore, "user2", "Password1234!".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[] { keyManager };

    X509TrustManager trustManager = new EasyTrustManager();
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { trustManager };

    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslcontext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext,
            SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)));

    HttpComponent http4 = context.getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class);
    http4.setClientConnectionManager(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry));
    final Endpoint https4Endpoint = http4
            .createEndpoint("https4://soafa-lite-staging:443/axis2/services/SigActService?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from(jettyEndpoint).to(https4Endpoint);
        }
    });

    context.start();

    context.stop();
}

private static class EasyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

};

private static class CTSKeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {
    private final KeyStore keystore;
    private final char[] privateKeyPassword;
    private final String privateKeyAlias;

    public CTSKeyManager(KeyStore keystore, String privateKeyAlias, char[] privateKeyPassword) {
        this.keystore = keystore;
        this.privateKeyAlias = privateKeyAlias;
        this.privateKeyPassword = privateKeyPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        String[] serverAliases = null;
        try {
            List<String> aliasList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int count = 0;
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = aliases.nextElement();
                aliasList.add(alias);
                count++;
            }
            serverAliases = aliasList.toArray(new String[count]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return serverAliases;
    }

    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        try {
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, privateKeyPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return privateKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return privateKeyAlias == null ? null : new String[] { privateKeyAlias };
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        X509Certificate[] x509 = null;
        try {
            Certificate[] certs = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
            if (certs == null || certs.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            x509 = new X509Certificate[certs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
                x509[i] = (X509Certificate) certs[i];
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return x509;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return privateKeyAlias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return privateKeyAlias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseEngineClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine) {
        return privateKeyAlias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseEngineServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine) {
        return privateKeyAlias;
    }
}

}
```

As far as I can tell, the trust should be fine between all keystores/truststores used on both sides of the proxy connections.

Here is my stack trace

```
[                qtp25584663-14] HttpProducer                   DEBUG Executing http POST method: https4://soafa-lite-staging:443/axis2/services/SigActService?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false
[                qtp25584663-14] DefaultErrorHandler            DEBUG Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-ubuntu-46528-1303140195358-0-1. On delivery attempt: 0 caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
[                qtp25584663-14] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-ubuntu-46528-1303140195358-0-1. Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:272)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:299)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:208)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:269)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelMultipartFilter.doFilter(CamelMultipartFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok working now, as it turns out, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of endpoints and protocols within Camel.  I should have been registering a scheme with the the https4 protocol and setting my SSLSocketFactory/SSLContext on it.  Since it Was registering a scheme with https it was never been using by the Http4 component.

Here is my working solution with 2 caveats.

1. Why can't I pass in a SchemeRegistry to the ThreadSafeClientConnManager and it is not used when constructing the HttpClient?  I have to the HttpClientConfigurer instead
2. Jetty has an issue where the Keystore and Truststore must be set by path on the SslSelectChannelConnector instead of via SSLContext (bug is in at least jetty 7.2.2 and 7.4.0 ->latest)

Code:

```
public class CamelProxy {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    final Endpoint jettyEndpoint = configureJetty(context);

    final Endpoint https4Endpoint = configureHttpClient(context);

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from(jettyEndpoint).to("log:com.smithforge.request?showAll=true").to(https4Endpoint);
        }
    });

    context.start();

    context.stop();
}

private static Endpoint configureHttpClient(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/brian/User2.p12")), "Password1234!".toCharArray());

    KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    truststore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/brian/jboss.truststore")), "changeit".toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyFactory.init(keystore, "Password1234!".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    trustFactory.init(truststore);

    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    sslcontext.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    final Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https4", 443, factory);
    registry.register(scheme);

    HttpComponent http4 = context.getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class);
    http4.setHttpClientConfigurer(new HttpClientConfigurer() {

        @Override
        public void configureHttpClient(HttpClient client) {
            client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(scheme);
        }

    });
    http4.setClientConnectionManager(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager());
    return http4
            .createEndpoint("https4://soafa-lite-staging:443/axis2/services/SigActService?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
}

private static Endpoint configureJetty(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
    JettyHttpComponent jetty = context.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);

    SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
    sslConnector.setPort(4443);
    sslConnector.setKeystore("/home/brian/jboss.keystore");
    sslConnector.setKeyPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setTruststore("/home/brian/jboss.truststore");
    sslConnector.setTrustPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setPassword("changeit");
    sslConnector.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    sslConnector.setAllowRenegotiate(true);

    Map<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector> connectors = new HashMap<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector>();
    connectors.put(4443, sslConnector);

    jetty.setSslSocketConnectors(connectors);
    return jetty.createEndpoint("jetty:https://localhost:4443/service");
}

// .to("log:com.smithforge.response?showHeaders=true");
}
```

Comment: Answer to caveat 1.  Camel always registers new https and https4 schemes to the SchemeRegistry of the ThreadSafeClientConnManager after its added to the HttpComponent which is bad, it should respect schemes that are already there.  That is why the ClientConfigurer is necessary to modify the SchemeRegistry after the registerPort() method of HttpComponent is done screwing with it

Comment: SchemeRegistry ,scheme are deprecated methods now can you get me code base without these deprecated methods.

Answer (score 4):

I got to work a ssl proxy with the following code

**The route**

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

public void configure() {

    configureSslForJetty();
    configureSslForHttp4();

    from("jetty:https://0.0.0.0:4443/topython/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .to("https4://backend.fake.com:4444/?q=ssl&bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
}
...
```

**Configuration for jetty** (provide a certificate when we are acting as a server)

```
private void configureSslForJetty()
{
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("c:\\Projects\\blah\\fakefilter.jks");
    ksp.setPassword("123456");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("export-password");

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
    jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
}
```

**Configuration for https4** (what certificate signers do we trust when acting as a client)

```
private void configureSslForHttp4()
{
    KeyStoreParameters trust_ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    trust_ksp.setResource("c:\\Projects\\blah\\fakeca.jks");
    trust_ksp.setPassword("123456");

    TrustManagersParameters trustp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    trustp.setKeyStore(trust_ksp);

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setTrustManagers(trustp);

    HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
    httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
}
```

}

**Things worth noting**

- you need to configure component `https4` not `http4`
- `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` in the command line provided lots of helpful logging

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having problems with '[unsafe ssl renegotiation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html)'.  Please verify that you're using the latest JDK/JRE (at least 1.6.0_24).

Comment: I am on latest greatest JRE/JDK

Comment: Is the client setup to send a certificate?  Could you comment the sslConnector.setNeedClientAuth(true) line and see if everything works properly?

Comment: I've got a partial answer, still debugging but I looks like apache camel is not using the SSLContext that was provided to the Http4 component.  I have debugged as far as the org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory and I can see the KeyManager is empty and the TrustManager contains the certs from java cacerts, NOT my truststore that I provided with the SSLContext.

Not using Camel, I have gotten this to work with a standalone embedded jetty using clientAuth and a HttpClient, so I knew is was something bad that Camel was doing when it configured these components for me.

Comment: _It looks like apache camel is not using the SSLContext that was provided to the Http4 component_ I think that you have to get the component **`https4`** in `context.getComponent("https4",HttpComponent.class);`, not http4 (as I did for several pointless hours...)