# Disable camel certificate validation in Camel 2.12

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-camel

I have a requirement to temporarily disable certificate validation in Camel 2.12. I am referencing a test web service that is currently supplying an invalid certificate and getting the following exception -

```
Exception in route: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building     failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Many of the example I've found on SO revolve around creating an HttpClientConfigurer and doing this -

```
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null); 

        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx, 
                SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); 
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager(); 
        SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry(); 
        sr.register(new Scheme("https4", 443, ssf));
```

These solutions require a version of the **configureHttpClient(HttpClient hc)** method that takes an **org.apache.http.client.HttpClient**. In my Camel version, this method takes an **org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient**, and has no reference to **getConnectionManager()**.

I've tried the JVM setting **com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false**, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [camel-http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) component, you need to use [camel-http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) component instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally managed to get this to work - thanks to the many postings out there that helped with some of the detail of what I was attempting to do, particular thanks to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706166/apache-camel-http-and-ssl). Step by step using Camel 2.12.1 -

My secure URL behind a proxy -

```
https4://someURL?proxyAuthHost=proxy.company.com&proxyAuthPort=8080&proxyAuthScheme=http
```

Creating the component to access the URL -

```
import org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent;
...
final HttpComponent myComponent = new HttpComponent();
myComponent.setClientConnectionManager(new PoolingClientConnectionManager());
myComponent.setHttpClientConfigurer(new myHttpClientConfigurer());
```

Note: the need to set a ClientConnectionManager only became clear when the code threw a NPE in HttpComponent at line 317 -

```
SchemeRegistry registry = clientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry();
```

**myHttpClientConfigurer.java**

```
 import org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpClientConfigurer;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 ...
 public class myHttpClientConfigurer implements HttpClientConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpClient(HttpClient hc) {
        try {
            Properties properties = loadProperties();
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            final String javaKeystoreFile = getJavaKeystoreFile(properties);
            final String keystorePassword = getKeystorePassword(properties);
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(javaKeystoreFile), keystorePassword.toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyFactory.init(trustStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

            TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            trustFactory.init(trustStore);

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslcontext.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

            TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {

                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }

            };

            SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.TLS, trustStore, keystorePassword, trustStore, null, trustStrategy, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            SchemeRegistry registry = hc.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, factory));

        catch ...
 }
```

Note that although the URL specifies "https4", the **new Scheme()** is "https". This seemed to be the only way I could get it to work, after stepping though the **HttpComponent** code in the debugger.

Comment: how we can call this class while communicating with the router, if you have GitHub reference code, could you please share?

Comment: @SrikanthJanapati did you get to know how to call this from router? Please share

Answer (score -2):

I have disabled validation as follows:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.util.jndi.JndiContext;
import org.apache.camel.util.jsse.KeyStoreParameters;
import org.apache.camel.util.jsse.SSLContextParameters;
import org.apache.camel.util.jsse.TrustManagersParameters;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{     
     JndiContext jndiContext = new JndiContext();
     jndiContext.bind("x509HostnameVerifier", new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());
     CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(jndiContext);   
     context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
         private void configurate(){
            KeyStoreParameters trust_ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
            trust_ksp.setResource("keystore/keystore.jks");
            trust_ksp.setPassword("qweqwe");
            TrustManagersParameters trustp = new TrustManagersParameters();
            trustp.setKeyStore(trust_ksp);
            SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
            scp.setTrustManagers(trustp);
            HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
            httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
         }          
             public void configure() throws Exception {
                 configurate();
                     from("file://test_folder")
                     .setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("/Action"))
                     .to("https4://localhost?x509HostnameVerifier=x509HostnameVerifier&authUsername=user&authPassword=pasword");    
        }
    });

     context.start();
     Thread.sleep(600000);
     context.stop();

    }
```